# MS Access validation rule for limiting selection of controlfield

Tags: validation, ms-access, checkbox

i got a table in Access with different columns. One of them contains only those checkbox elements which can be (un-/)checked. Now i need to create a validation rule to limit the amount of selected boxes in the tables column.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds as if your data isn't normalised correctly. Please post up your table fields  and or a picture of your table design.

Comment: I only have one table that stores data about people. The table has several columns (name, age, etc.) and one which contains the combobox (yes / no field). This column contains an attribute like "male", so you can select it for every person who is male and not select it for everyone who is not. Now i want to limit the maximum amount of male people in that table so i need to limit the amount of selected comboboxes in the column.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Certainly not in the table design. I'll be honest I can only think of a really kludgey way of doing it on a form using DCount() and the beforeupdate event. It also doesn't make a lot of sense in the real world. If you have a table of employees , I've no idea why you would want to or even could only have 10 males for example.... ? ? Maybe you need to give us the real world data and purpose of this?

Comment: I dont think so too.
Maybe that was a bad example. 
Another example is that there must be at least two first-aid-responders in a company.

But that's okay. Maybe I can find a workaround via a second table for roles.